# Why do the rank $r$ matrices form a manifold?

Tags: matrices, differential-geometry, manifolds, matrix-rank

I keep coming accross this statement that the set of rank-$r$ $m \times n$ matrices form a manifold. In both sources referenced below, the authors say "it is known", but I am having trouble finding the justification.

The statement can be seen in Section 3 eq. 1 [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2009.01893.pdf), and on slide 11 [here](https://www.math.fsu.edu/%7Ewhuang2/pdf/slides_2016-GMDL.pdf).

Comment: My instinct is to first try to prove it when $m=r.$

Answer (score 3):

This is a standard exercise (see, for example, exercise 13 on p. 27 of Guillemin and Pollack's *Differential Topology*). It is an application of the preimage theorem. If you assume the matrix is of the form
$$X=\left[\begin{array}{c|c}A & B \\\hline C & D \end{array}\right],$$
where $A$ is $r\times r$ invertible, then show that $X$ has rank $r$ if and only if $D-CA^{-1}B = 0$. (So you need to show that $0$ is a regular value of the map $M_{m\times n} \to M_{(m-r)\times (n-r)}$.)

Comment: This will only tell you that a piece of the space of matrices of rank $r$ is a manifold, no? You need to do this for all choices of an $r\times r$ minor and patch.

Comment: I said "if" — one needs to show that locally one can always change coordinates so that it is of this form, yes. Perhaps my "answer" is indeed only a "sketch" or a "hint."

Answer (score 3):

Consider the action of the Lie group $$GL(m, \mathbb{R}) \times GL(n, \mathbb{R}) \times M_{m\times n} \to M_{m\times n}, (P, Q, X) \to PXQ^{-1}$$
Matrices of rank $r$ are identified with one of the orbits  of $GL(m, \mathbb{R}) \times GL(n, \mathbb{R}) $,  which is a homegenous space,  identified with the Quotient of a Lie group by a closed subgroup,  and it is well known that that $G/H$ is a smooth manifold(in fact real analytic) whenever $G$ is a lie group and $H$ closed subgroup. [see Closed subgroup theorem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed-subgroup_theorem)

Comment: Thanks, this is definitely true in my case.

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand\im{\operatorname{image}}\newcommand\gl{\operatorname{gl}}\newcommand\GL{\operatorname{GL}}$
I find it easier to do this abstractly. Let $V$ be an $n$-dimensional vector space and $W$ an $m$-dimensional vector space. Let $\gl_r(V,W)$ be the space of linear maps from $V$ to $W$ with rank $r$. Let $G(V,k)$ and $G(W,k)$ be the Grassmannian of $k$-planes in $V$ and $W$ respectively.

There is a natural surjection
\begin{align*}
\pi: \gl_r(V,W) &\rightarrow G(V,n-r)\times G(W,r)\\
A &\mapsto (\ker A, \im A).
\end{align*}
Also naturally associated to each $A$ is the linear isomorphism
\begin{align*}
[A]: V/\ker A &\rightarrow \im A\\
[v] &\mapsto A(v).
\end{align*}
Given $(K,L) \in G(V,n-r)\times G(W,r)$, this defines a bijection
$$
\pi^{-1}(K,L) \rightarrow \gl_r(V/K,L),
$$
Using affine coordinates on $G(V,n-r)$ and $G(m,r)$, you can use this to define coordinate charts on $\gl_r(V,W)$ and show that the transition maps are smooth.